# How to validate string that can't have certain characters using parsley

Tags: regex, parsley.js

I need to validate input type text that doesn't contain these characters `" ' < >` I've tried:

```
pattern=".*[^&#x22;'<>].*"
```

and

```
pattern="[^&#x22;'<>]+"
```

but they don't work. It appears valid if there is one valid character.

Comment: @ndn `pattern="^[^&#x22;'<>]+$"` work you can add this as an answer

Comment: is there anything like negation in your lang like `!/[&#x22;'<>]/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your current attempts is that they try to match one (or at least one) character, which is not one of the listed as undesirable characters. Instead, you should make sure this applies to all characters from the start (`^`) til the end (`$`).

```
pattern="^[^&#x22;'<>]+$"
```

Comment: Versions before 2.2.0-rc2 didn't properly anchor the pattern. In 2.2.0-rc2+, `[^&#x22;'<>]+` is sufficient